# ColdFusion: cftooltips display on one site but not another on same server

Tags: coldfusion, tooltip

I just deployed a new site, call it SiteA, that uses cftooltip, but the tooltips are not displaying. When I hover over the link, nothing happens. SiteB has been running on the same server for a long time, and it's tooltips display fine.  The folders for SiteA, SiteB and CFIDE are all in inetpub/wwwroot.

My browser reports the following when trying to display tooltips on SiteA:

'ColdFusion is undefined'
'YAHOO' is undefined.

It would seem that SiteA can't find what it needs in cfide/scripts, but SiteB doesn't have this problem.  In the CF Admin, I have a mapping to cfide.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance for help.

Peter

Comment: Are you getting any 404s on JS files in these requests that aren't working properly?

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly a solution, but you can cut and paste the CFIDE/scripts folder into the webroot of SiteA, which should at least get it working until you work it out!

Things to check are the mappings (obviously), but also any URL rewriting etc; look into chrome dev tools or firebug to see what is being returned from the missing .js call (i.e is it an IIS or apache 404, or something else?)

Comment: Thanks. I found the problem: I need to create a virtual directory for cfide/scripts.